# android: detect if settings(com.android.settings) is open

Tags: android, service, package

i want to when user try to open `Settings` app or package `com.android.settings` (all app in `Settings` like battery, wifi, sound, etc), it will show up `Toast`. I will create in `Service`. Here's my code :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //if(Settings is open){
      //Toast.makeText  . . . 
    } 

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

I have already all in `stackoverflow`, but still doesn't work. I apologize for my english, and will be glad if you suggest a solution. Thank You. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all the currently running tasks, and loop their package names until your specified package is found (or not):

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager
        .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
    if (task.baseActivity.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.settings")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }               
}
```

Also add this permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: sorry, but why is always show `Toast`. I just want to when user click `Settings`, or `Wifi` . .

Comment: So, how just if `Settings` activity is open/show, no start/running in tasks. Just if activity is open/show? Can do that?

Comment: I don't understand. You run this code in your activity and it checks if settings are currently opened. You can have only 1 activity visible at a time.

Comment: But when `Setting` are closed, Toast always show . .

Comment: @dtnder remove the settings activity from Recent Activities and it will not.

Comment: okay, i understand now. But, how to remove `Settings` from recent activities?

Comment: @dtnder On my device, I just swipe it from the [Recent Activities](http://d0od.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/android-recent-apps-list.jpg).

Comment: @dtnder A lot of questions my friend :) AFAIK you can't do these things to an activity that doesn't belong to your package: you can't kill it, you can't detect if it's visible or not.